# Kotlin: Unexpected value for 2 Int multiplication

Tags: kotlin, multiplication

I've written a function to round a value in billion, here is my code:

```
private fun roundBillion(value: Double): Int {
    val a = (value / 1000000).toInt()
    val res = a * 1000000
    return res
}
```

but when I execute the function I get an unexpected value in `res` variable. here is variables inspection when the break point is on return statement:

> value = 1.7636265135946954E11
>
> a = 176362
>
> res = 268340864

I can't figure out where the problem is!

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: The value `176362 * 1000000` does not fit in a 32-bit `Int` so you get integer overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are experiencing is an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is `1.7976931348623157E308`.

`Int.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`. Your number in the calculation (i.e. `176362000000`) exceeds that.

Comment: This is overflow, but does the overflow result in wrapping? Because if I multiply `964632435` by `10` I get `1056389759` not `646324350`. Not sure why the overflow result is what it is. Thanks.